# setText() on any view

Tags: java, android, view, settext

I wanna set text to the general **View** class and if the **View** doesn't have a **setText()** method like **ImageView** just throw an exception for the user. I already tried using `instanceof` but I don't know how many views have **setText()** and I can't cover custom views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setText` method is defined in `TextView` class, any other class(like Button,EditText) which has `setText` method, they get it from `TextView` class by inheritance.

So to check if a view has `setText` method or not you just have to simply check if it is a reference of `TextView` class or not.

So you can do it like this:

```
if (view instanceof TextView)
        {
            ((TextView) view).setText("Type whatever you want to set");
        }
        else
        {
            // throw your exception here
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not realize they all extend from TextView :)